# How to get first few letter from specific excel cell and use it as input for part of next output

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro in excel using VBA where I am looking for open a file in another file.

Look at cell "E5" Now E5 value will be 8A1234S/0.  I want to create new worksheet(Tab) in the main file and use the E5 value to rename that tab. Now since my E5 value has "/" in it.

It can not be used to name the tab. If I run this code it creates a tab but name comes out to be with name "False"

Here is the code.

```
Sub Filling_List()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sName As String 'add sName declaration
Dim uploadfile As Variant
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim AB As String
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
uploadfile = Application.GetOpenFilename() 
If uploadfile = "False" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(uploadfile)
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Que & Tsc Cal")
```

Now I want to use only first 7 letters from tab E5. Also if I can read all letter and just drop "/" it will work also

```
AB = ws1.Range("E5").Value = Left(E5, 7)
sName = AB & " " & ws1.Range("B4") 'assign value from two cells
```

I also tried this by not using AB but didnt work.

```
sName = ws1.Range("E5, 7").Value & " " & ws1.Range("B4")
```

A

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim wslTest As Worksheet
Set wslTest = wb.Worksheets(sName)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Tab: " & sName & " already exists.", vbInformation
    wslTest.Activate
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0


Set wb = ThisWorkbook


wb.Worksheets("ArF Templete").Copy After:=wb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
wb.ActiveSheet.Name = sName

If sName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `Left` function like this

```
Dim SheetName as String
SheetName = Left(Range("E5"), 7))
```

Comment: Thank you worked very well. Somehow it is creating the new worksheet in between and not at the end of the sheet. Can it be created at the end. 

anything wrong in

    wb.Worksheets("ArF Templete").Copy After:=wb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    wb.ActiveSheet.Name = sName

    If sName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub